# Grails: excluding a JS file from minification

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I read tons of documentation on `asset-pipeline` Grails plugin, but found no definite answers and I can not exclude a single stupid JS file from being minified.

Grails is in ver. `3.3.6` and assetPipelineVersion `2.14.1`.

**Goal**:
Stop minifying `grails-app/assets/javascripts/json-tree/json-tree.js`.

**What I tried**:

I changed the `assets` block in `build.gradle`:

```
assets {
  minifyJs = true
  minifyCss = true
  includes = []
  excludes = [ '**/json-tree.js' ] // tried also with 'json-tree/json-tree.js'
}
```

I also added a section to my `application.yml`:

```
grails:
  assets:
    excludes: ['json-tree/*.js'] # also tried with **
```

**Problem**: the file still gets minified.

How can I solve the problem?

Also, how the assets pipeline should be configured: per `build.gradle` or `application.yml` or both?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with following :

```
grails.assets.minifyOptions.excludes = ["json-tree/json-tree.js"]
```

To exclude single file you can try above otherwise you can exclude whole folder from minify

```
grails.assets.minifyOptions.excludes = ["json-tree/*.js"]
```

For more information you check [documentation](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html)

Hope this will help you